# How to use the $content variable within a module in Drupal 7, Ubercart 3

Tags: drupal, variables, attributes, ubercart

I'm running the latest versions of Drupal 7 & Ubercart 3.  I'm trying to capture date from the $content variable for use within a module.  Specifically I am trying to capture data from a custom product field and display that data inline certain product attributes/options.

The point of this is to create a custom description for each attribute for each product.

It seems the $content variable is not available from uc_attribute.module.  Using $content['field_original_size']; returns: undefined variable content .  If I use the render function I am returned no errors nor data.  Here is what I have so far:

```
function theme_uc_attribute_option($variables) {
$original_size = render($content['field_original_size']);

if($variables['option'] == 'Original'){
  $output = $variables['option'];
  $output .= ', ' . $original_size;
  if ($variables['price']) {
    $output .= ', ' . $variables['price'];
  }
}
else{
  $output = $variables['option'];
  if ($variables['price']) {
    $output .= ', ' . $variables['price'];
  }
}
  return $output;
}
```

It seems that th easiest way to do this, may be with the token_replace() function, so heres what I am trying now but does not work.  There are no errors, but the token does not get replaced.

```
function theme_uc_attribute_option($variables) {
if($variables['option'] == 'Original'){
  $output = $variables['option'];
  if ($variables['price']) {
    $output .= ', ' . '[node:field-medium]';
    $output .= ', ' . $variables['price'];
    token_replace($output);
  }
}
else{
  $output = $variables['option'];
  if ($variables['price']) {
    $output .= ', ' . $variables['price'];
  }
}
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print out the $variables, and see if what you need is somewhere in there.

Comment: Thanks! A good thought, but the only data stored in $variables is the option name and price.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you didn't declare your function using a reference to $variables. I believe it should be called as `function theme_uc_attribute_option(&$variables) {}`. That tells PHP to send a reference to the variable instead of the *value* of the variable. When the value is sent, any changes to it are local only. If a reference is used, the changes make their way back to the variable. See the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference) for details. I just noticed how old this is.